# How many subsets?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many subsets of size 4 of the set S={1,2,....20} contain at least 1 of the elements 1,2,3,4,5?

$${5 \choose 4}{15 \choose 0}+{5 \choose 3}{15 \choose 1}+{5 \choose 2}{15 \choose 2}+{5 \choose 1}{15 \choose 3} + \binom50 \binom{15}4$$

5 "special elements"
15 "regular elements"

Is my answer correct?

Comment: Look at the last two terms again, I think you meant something different.

Comment: ah yea typos! besides that its ok?

Comment: ... Contain _at least one_ element. You'll want to drop the last term. The rest is fine.

Comment: oh righ thanks!

Comment: You'll want to accept Meelo's answer then since there's nothing more to add. Note that `{n \choose k}` is superseeded by `\binom{n}{k}` for syntactical reasons ;)

Comment: Please don't change the meaning of a question after it was answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your answer is almost correct - the last term is confusing and also wrong. Consider that any subset of size $4$ containing at least one of the $5$ special elements can be partitioned into a subset $S$ of special elements (of size $1$ through $4$) and a subset $R$ of regular elements (of size $0$ through $3$). Thus, the correct answer would simply be:
$${5\choose 4}{15\choose 0}+{5\choose 3}{15\choose 1}+{5\choose 2}{15\choose 2}+{5\choose 1}{15\choose 3}$$
where we take the sum over the possible sizes of $S$ and $R$. This is basically what you have, except without the confusing last term, which would seem to represent the case if $S$ had size $0$ - which is not a case we are interested in - that case represents have no special elements.

Answer (score 3):

The complementary subsets – those of size $4$ which contain *none* of $1,2,3,4,5$ are $\displaystyle \binom{15}{4}$, and there are $\displaystyle \binom{20}{4}$ subsets of size $4$ in all. Hence the number of subsets of size $4$ which contain at least one of these numbers is equal to

$$\binom{20}{4}-\binom{15}{4}=\frac{20!}{4!\,16!}-\frac{15!}{4!\,11!}=3480.$$